# Is there any other way than float:left to stack elements to the right of another element?

Tags: html, css, grid, css-float

I'm trying to align four elements like this:

```
||=||    B
||A||    C
||=||    D
```

`A` is an image, and the other three elements are div tags. All elements have a class of `span_2` with the following CSS:

```
.span_2 {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

However, this gives me the following layout:

```
||=||    B
||A||    
||=||    
  C      D
```

I know I can set `float:left` on all four elements, to get what I want, but I'm wondering if there is any other CSS way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could put the `B C D` elements in a container div with the same class `span_2`.

Example:

```
<img src="image.jpg" class="span_2" />
<div class="span_2">
    <div class="span_2">B</div>
    <div class="span_2">C</div>
    <div class="span_2">D</div>
</div>
```

For correct alignment you'll need to add `vertical-align: top;` to the class, too.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/cCU89/1/

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

**HTML**

```
<div id="LeftHold">
    <img src="#">
</div>
<div id="RightHold">
    <div class="Right" id="B"></div>
    <div class="Right" id="C"></div>
    <div class="Right" id="D"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#LeftHold{
   width:100px;
   height:100px;
   float:left;
}
#RightHold{
   width:100px;
   height:100px;
   float:left;
}
.Right{
   width:100px;
   height:25px;
}
```

I hope that helps!

**Without Float**

You can use a table! :)

Comment: Uhhm, he wanted a solution without float ;)